# Xamarin.Forms: Position labels in StackLayout?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.forms.listview

I was finally able to display several `Labels` in my ListView. My xaml looks like this. As you can see, I just slapped 4 `Labels` and that's what's being displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
             x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">

    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MapGrid">
            <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="200" 
                  x:Name="MyMap" IsShowingUser="true"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Text="Show list" x:Name="Button_DisplayList"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" x:Name="listSection" IsVisible="false" HeightRequest="200">
            <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="200">
                                <Label Text="{Binding StoreName}" FontSize="10"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="14"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Street}" FontSize="8"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding State}" FontSize="16"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

So far, so good. For anyone interested, there's a [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6qBF.png).

But instead of setting the labels one next to the other, I want to position in different places. For example, `Label Name` will be in the top left corner and `Label Desc` will be below, while `Label Lon` will be in the bottom right corner and `Label Lat` will be horizontally centered.

So my questions are:

1) How can I position these labels within the available space? Is there something like an `html` table *equivalent* that I can use to position the labels at specific places?

2) How can I change the height of each row? The reason I set `StackLayout Orientation` to *Horizontal* is because two of the labels did not fit if I set to *Vertical* (that's why it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6qBF.png)). I tried `HeightRequest` and `MinimumHeightRequest` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

A [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) should give you what you want. You can set the number of [rows and columns and the height for each row and the width for each column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns). Height and width settings can be absolute (you provide the explicit height/width value), auto (based on content), or proportional with a "*" value. You can also set an item to [span multiple rows and/or columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#spans)... much like an HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement using `Grid` layout like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           FontSize="10"
                           Text="{Binding StoreName}"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           FontSize="14"
                           Text="{Binding Description}"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           FontSize="8"
                           Text="{Binding Street}"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="3"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Text="{Binding State}"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
<Label Text="My text" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
```

**and make sure the** **HorizontalOptions in StackLayout is** `HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"`